# Is the following set of infinite absolutely convex combinations closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and let $(x_n)$  be a weakly-null sequence in X.

Let $A:=\{\sum_{n=1}^∞  a_nx_n :(a_n)∈B_{l_1}\}$ , 
where $B_{l_1}$    is the closed unit ball of the sequence space $l_1$  .

Is the set $A$ closed in $X$?

A hint for this question: Take X to be $c_0$ or $ℓ_p$ for $1<p<∞$ and take $x_n$ to be the nth standard basis vector.

According to the hint the set $A$ seems to be not closed. But from this point on, still I could not see a sequence in $A$ which has no limit point in the set $A$. What would be the relevant sequence in $A$ which has no its limit point in $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $S:(\ell^1,\sigma(\ell^1,c_0)) \to (X,\sigma(X,X'))$, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n$ is continuous: Since $\sigma(X,X')$ is an *initial* topology you only have to check the continuity of $\phi \circ S$ for all $\phi\in X'$ and this follows from $\phi(x_n) \to 0$.
By Alaoglu, the unit ball of $\ell^1$ is $\sigma(\ell^1,c_0)$-compact and as a continuous image $S(B_{\ell^1})$ is even weakly compact.